# How to find the most similar strings in a database to an input string

Tags: php, mysql, database, similarity

I am storing error reports and stacktraces from javascript code in a database. I would like to group similar reports together however due to inconsistency among browsers and browser versions I am unable to use naive string comparison

I am willing to use either sql or no sql databases but preferably sql and also I can use elastic seach or solr if needed. I would love this to be realtime with the submission of the error report rather than a cron job.

As for the scale of things there will most likely be 10s to 100s of thousands of error reports. And most likely there will be 100s to 1000s of error reports that I need to classify as the same to reduce the number of reports that developers need to deal with

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine why you would want to do this, sounds like less hassle then cross browser testing :P

In anycase, without a database schema, or a question mark in your question it is a bit hard to answer.

I would not go with a no-sql solution, but instead go with a structure that tried to index on things that you are interested in splitting, i.e. if you want all "undefined variables" in one report then put anything containing that into a table and index it. This will make things super quick.

I guess what I am saying is sort the stack trace before storage and it makes reporting easier.

You could also try fulltext search: http://www.petefreitag.com/item/477.cfm

Comment: This is a second line of defense for code that has been released to production. I do my best to normalize the collected info but some variation still exists. I just did not want small variations to be filed separately. Full text search sounds promising. Thank you